# $C^{1,\alpha}$ everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove that if $f : B_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz-continuous in $B_1$ and
$$|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)| \le c |x-y|^\alpha$$

for a.e. $x$, $y \in B_1$, then
$$f \in C^{1,\alpha}(B_1).$$

Here $n \ge 1$ but I don't really care of $n=1$. I have set
$$ B_1 = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x| \le 1\}. $$

A lot of people may rebut that it's somehow trivial. Let me explain **why it is not that trivial**.

Let $D \subset B_1$ be the a such that $|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)| \le c |x-y|^\alpha\, \forall x$, $y \in D$, and let $g : B_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Hölder-continuous extension of $\nabla f$ from $D$ to $B_1$.

Now, if I pick $x\in B_1 \setminus D$, there is no need for $\nabla f(x)$ neither to exist nor to be equal to $g(x)$ if $\nabla f(x)$ exists (though I believe the latter is not the problem). So that we have to show them both.

**P.S.** I'm pretty sure this is true, let's say I think it's 99% true. Of course I would not have written this question down if I had believed it's 100% true.

**Bonus Track**

Is the result still true if we replace $|B_1\setminus D| = 0$ with $D$ dense in $B_1$?